# I am able to create button without border, but it is not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create button with `no border`, I am able to do it, button once i remove border through css, it is not working in `Firefox` and `Chrome`,Pls help.

```
<button type="button" id="submitButton" >Submit</button>

.container #emailDiv #submitButton{
float:left;
margin-top:368px;
margin-left:-151px;
background-image:url(images\\but-middle.gif);
background-repeat:x-repeat; 
width:50px;
border:none;
 }
```

Comment: should work. what exactly is not working?

Comment: hi is this a `form` submit button or what kind of button is this

Comment: I found the resolution myself,I just removed border from left and right side of button and then it started working("was able to click it and submit the form")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the border cant detract your layout just try this

```
.container #emailDiv #submitButton{
float:left;
margin-top:368px;
margin-left:-151px;
background-image:url(images\\but-middle.gif);
background-repeat:x-repeat; 
width:50px;
border:1px solid #fff transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: thanx for replying but i jst want to remove the border of the button,as their are two images which I need to use at the both ends of the button to make it rounded

Comment: did you try to have a `height` maybe i can help you more if i can see the image button

Comment: This is the updated code, I tried to add the height too, still the button is not being clicked `float:left;
 margin-top:368px;
 margin-left:-151px;
 background-image:url(images\\but-middle.gif);
 background-repeat:x-repeat; 
 width:50px;
 border:none !important;
 height:19px;
 color:white;`

Comment: hi it easy to us to play with your problem if you have a [fiddle](www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I am new here, how to do that??

Comment: just visit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/) put your code there so we can see what is your problem and link to us after you make your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
.container #emailDiv #submitButton{
float:left;
margin-top:368px;
margin-left:-151px;
background-image:url(images\\but-middle.gif);
background-repeat:x-repeat; 
width:50px;
border:none;
-moz-border:none
-webkit-border:none
```

Comment: I am able to remove the border, but once I remove the border of the button, The button stops working in Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

try to import no border? it might be inherited by some other divs.

```
border:none !important;
```

Comment: When you use an ID in the button you don't need to define the parent of that element in css. "#submitButton {/* css code */}" fot your background-image should be "background-image:url(images/but-middle.gif);"

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me...

Just look @ this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pDtwE/18/) / [Demo..](http://jsfiddle.net/pDtwE/19/)

```
#submitButton {
    background-color:green;
   background-image:url(images\\but-middle.gif);
   background-repeat:x-repeat;
   width:50px;
   border:none;
  -moz-border:none
  -webkit-border:none
```

}

Comment: I dnt understd, wt else can be the problem, its still not working